# A website open in another tab auto refreshes when I log into gmail

Tags: email, security, gmail

There is a forum site that I have joined recently. Currently I am logged into it and in the other tab I have my gmail opened. I have noticed that everytime I logout or login to my gmail account, the forum-site tab automatically refreshes itself.

It is fine if they are just tracking if I am logged into any of my several gmail accounts. My main concern is - Can they get the email address I am logging into. I am pretty sure, it will be not be easy to get the password though ? Likewise, are they able to track or log all my gmail-accounts.

I would actually consider it a breach of my privacy. What are the possible information they could harness such environment.

Comment: This looks to be offtopic for this site. Perhaps a better place for this topic is [security.se].

Comment: Feel free to migrate the thread to said forum, if it feels appropriate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming. To learn about topics that can be asked here see [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this issue on Chrome only or on other browsers as well ?. The issue must be with Chrome browser only, because a website cannot access information about websites opened in other tabs

Comment: The two tabs definitely seem to communicate though. Else why would the site immediately refresh as I login / logout of gmail. This is not a valid answer.